# Make postgres full text search (tsvector) act like ILIKE to search inside words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, search, full-text-search, tsvector

So let's say I search for 'Blerg'. And I have a item with the name SomethingblergSomething.

If I do an ILIKE search in postgres (and rails) like this:

```
where("name ILIKE ?", "%#{ 'Blerg' }%")
```

It will return the result 'SomethingBlergSomething' because it contains Blerg.

Is there a way to make the faster tsvector do a similar style of searching inside a word:

```
where("(to_tsvector('english', name) @@ to_tsquery(?))", ('Blerg' + ':*'))
```

The above query will not return 'SomethingBlergSomething'.

So how do I make tsvector act like ILIKE when searching inside words.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Are you aware of trigram search, provided by the additional module [**pg_trgm**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html)? That seems more appropriate for your use case than text search.

With a trigram index in place (GIN or GiST) you can use your original `ILIKE` predicate and get index support for it. You need Postgres 9.1+ for that.

Details:

- [PostgreSQL LIKE query performance variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1566717/postgresql-like-query-performance-variations/13452528#13452528)
- [Pattern matching with LIKE, SIMILAR TO or regular expressions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/10696/3684)